# How to display a flutter modalBottomSheet when user taps a BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to display a modalBottomsheet when user taps a BottomNavigationBarItem, i tried to put the code in a function and call it in the body of a scaffold but that did not work.. any ideas on how to do this? see my code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';

class More extends StatefulWidget {
  More({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MoreState createState() => _MoreState();
}

class _MoreState extends State<More> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Modal Bottom Sheet',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: displayModal());
  }

  displayModal() {
    showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container(child: Text("data")),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showBottomSheet` is a async function. you should use something like this

```
 body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              displayModal();
            },
            child: Text("show dialog"),
          ),
        )
```

if you want to show the dialog on widget load, call the dialog in initState of the statefull widget

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      displayModal();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this will just place a button on the screen and it won't display modal until user clicks button. my goal is to display the modal as soon as user clicks the BottomNavigationBarItem and navigates to the new screen.

Comment: if you want to show it on the widget load, you can make the call on the initState of the state. I ll update the code.

Comment: forget to add `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`, please check now